# illegal character and parse error

Tags: parse-error, bc, illegal-characters

---

top -n 2 -d 5 | grep Cpu | awk 'NR==2' | sed -e "s/\%//g" | sed -e "s/\us,//g" > temp

cpu_value=`awk '{print $2}' temp`

### cpu_calc=`echo "scale=4; 100 - $cpu_value" | bc`

I am getting the below error:

(standard_in) 1: illegal character: ^[
(standard_in) 1: parse error

Comment: What does scale to bc? if you just do `echo "scale=4; 100 - $cpu_value"` the result is what bc has to process and bc is who is generating the error. on my laptop it produced `scale=4; 100 - 6,8` I think you have to replace the ',' with a '.'

Answer (score 0):

Just Add tr to replace the `,` with a `.`

```
cpu_calc=`echo "scale=4; 100 - $cpu_value" | tr , . | bc`
```

It seems to work on my laptop.

Edit:
As you should know the decimal separator and the thousands separators are different on different countries, and therefore can also be different if some commands have country/language specific number formatting.
In Spain we write `42.571,93` in other countries you can see `42,571.93` for computers however the correct form is `42571.93` (this number is just an example).

Comment: Thanks n Sorry this is not working.             Its working when I am trying the below, I hope the problem is with the variable                   bash-3.2$ echo "scale=4; 100 - 6.6" | bc 93.4

Comment: Is the output message still the same?

Comment: You can use `LC_ALL=C` before the command to force C-style locale, e. g. without any local quirks and (of course) overriding any locale settings.